# Display all github issues for a repository on one single page?

Tags: github, github-api

I want to quickly scan / search all issues for a particular project (it has around [200 issues](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed)).

Looking one page at a time is very slow. Especially when using ctrl + f to search for a symbol (which is occasionally necessary since github's native search doesn't return search results for symbols, only strings).

How can I see all of a repo's issues on a single page?

Note: I am open to using the github api if no website solution is possible

Comment: By seeing all repo's issues, you want to see all open/closed issue titles and bodies? Or is your request to be to search for symbols. Have an example?

Comment: @osowskit I would be happy with simply all closed or open issues's titles on one page. The thing I want to search for is the `<` symbol among the titles of the ~200 (closed) issues in the link in the question.

Comment: What would you like to do with them. There may be an easier way of tracking them or getting what you want

Comment: @osowskit The goal is to see if any issue is about a topic that involves the less than symbol. I will simply scrape them and `grep("\<")` if github doesn't provide a way to conveniently search.

Comment: @osowskit github has a lot of cool features like appending `.patch` and `.diff` to urls, so I figured maybe they'd thought about this and you could put `&resultsPerPage=200` or similar on the end of an issues url. That's what I was hoping for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enumerate all the issues in the repository at once.  GitHub requires pagination not only because rendering all of the items at once can lead to an unusably slow page that can crash the browser, but also because it puts a large amount of load on their servers.

The API does have pagination, but the number of items per page is [limited to 100](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).  Be sure to use the `Link` header as recommended if you decide to use it anyway.